# Firefox "restart" icon broken

Tags: firefox

For some time already I've noticed that my Firefox has no "restart" icon. When a Firefox update is installed, I see a "missing icon" icon instead:

[image]

When I click this icon I get the normal "You should restart Firefox" popup, only with a larger, blurrier version of this same icon.

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04, up to date, and a few extensions ("Classic theme restorer" among them), but it's difficult to find out if one extension is the culprit, since if I disable some, I have to restart Firefox for it take effect, and then the icon is obviously gone and I have to wait for the next update. It's also difficult to try with a new default profile.

I've tried purging and reinstalling firefox, with apparently no effect, but maybe I missed something.

(EDIT posted as an answer)

Comment: Make an answer of your edit to become an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As I've been asked to post this as an answere, here I go:)

Well, writing here made me research this farther. First I notice that I can run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

to force the "restart needed" notification, even if it's just reinstalling the same version. Then I started Firefox from a console and saw:

```
(firefox:20019): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'reboot-notifier' for stock: Icon 'reboot-notifier' not present in theme
```

so it's `reboot-notifier` what's missing. Then:

```
$ locate reboot-notifier
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/24/reboot-notifier.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/reboot-notifier.svg
```

Hmm... that's too few, and I'm using the Oxygen theme in KDE, not Humanity. Where can I get the icon?

```
$ apt-file search reboot-notifier
elementary-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/24/reboot-notifier.svg
elementary-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/32/reboot-notifier.svg
elementary-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary/apps/48/reboot-notifier.svg
gnome-colors-common: /usr/share/icons/gnome-colors-common/16x16/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-colors-common: /usr/share/icons/gnome-colors-common/22x22/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-colors-common: /usr/share/icons/gnome-colors-common/24x24/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-colors-common: /usr/share/icons/gnome-colors-common/32x32/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-colors-common: /usr/share/icons/gnome-colors-common/scalable/apps/reboot-notifier.svg
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux: /usr/share/icons/GartoonRedux/16x16/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux: /usr/share/icons/GartoonRedux/22x22/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux: /usr/share/icons/GartoonRedux/24x24/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux: /usr/share/icons/GartoonRedux/32x32/apps/reboot-notifier.png
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux: /usr/share/icons/GartoonRedux/scalable/apps/reboot-notifier.svg
humanity-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/24/reboot-notifier.svg
humanity-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/reboot-notifier.svg
update-notifier: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/reboot-notifier.png
update-notifier: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/reboot-notifier.png
update-notifier: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/reboot-notifier.png
xubuntu-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/24/reboot-notifier.png
xubuntu-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/32/reboot-notifier.png
xubuntu-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/reboot-notifier.png
```

Fortunately, I have another system where the icon was working, and there I could see that `locate reboot-notifier` said the `hicolor` ones were installed. Also `update-notifier` is the only package that's not a specific icon theme (although the file paths look like a specific icon theme). So I install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install update-notifier
```

which asked for a total of 49 packages to be installed (why was this not installed already? why do I have to install all this to get the icon? why does Firefox not requiere this?).

This has apparently solved my problem, now I get a nice icon:

[image]